# django - python

Tags: python, django, postgis, geodjango

I am very new to django, python and ubuntu command line. I've been installing an application on PC's and this is my third one. Ive come across this error and am not sure where else to look. When I run
python manage.py syncdb
i receive the following error

```
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Cannot determine PostGIS version for database "winepad". GeoDjango requires at least PostGIS version 1.3. Was the database created from a spatial database template?
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Check Your PostGIS Version. it must be atleast 1.3.

Answer (score 1):

Have you gone through this character-building documentation:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/gis/install/

?

We need to know more about versions of things and what steps you took to come to this error.  Otherwise, the error is pretty informative.  The database that your settings refer to must not have been created with postgis 1.3+ from a spatial database template.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder since you say that you are new,, Do you realize that you are attempting to install a Django package that has geo requirements and therefore assumes that you have a correct version of postgres-sql up and running (which is a somewhat difficult install itself) 
You might want to start with something simpler that just uses the sql-lite database look in the Djano settings file to see what the database setting is....